# PostgreSQL in Docker - access from host

Tags: postgresql, docker

I've been trying to get access to PostgreSQL running in a docker container. I'm able to connect to the PostgreSQL from within the adminer on `localhost:8080`, which is another container, but I'm not able to connect from my host machine, although I'm mapping the port `5432` to the host machine.

As a container's IP to connect to I've been using an IP address fetched from "`docker inspect <postgre_container>`" - usually `172.21.0.2/3`.

This is what my docker-compose.yml looks like:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:9.6.0
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: root
      POSTGRES_USER: root
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080

volumes:
  pgdata:
```

I'll be glad for any hints, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IP address shown using `docker inspect` is the *internal* IP address within the container. Since you are using port mapping with external port 5432, you should access Postgres via localhost:5432 (e.g. 127.0.0.1:5432).

Comment: Thanks mate, for some reason "localhost" did not work when I was trying to connect to it, but 127.0.0.1 works.